# Bayesian propagation of classification uncertainty to estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, error-propagation

I have 10 objects which can be classified as A,B,C,D with some probability. For example:

object 1: 40% A, 20% B, 30% C, 10% D

object 2: 10% A, 30% B, 40% C, 20% D
...

The question I want to ask is what fraction of my objects is A, B, C, D. I don't understand how to model the uncertainty given the discrete nature of classification and I can't find how to propagate the uncertainty to the fraction estimator afterwards. Perhaps I don't understand because the question I pose is wrong in the first place. It is important that I do it in a Bayesian way. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The objects are independent.

Comment: You can get the expected percentage by category just from linearity of expectation.  Anything else would depend on the dependence between the objects (which we aren't told anything about) and the computation would be messy (even if the objects were independent).

Comment: I added that the objects are independent. Could you explain in math what you mean?

Comment: Say  object $i$ has probabilities $(A_i, \cdots, D_i)$.  Then the expected portion of type A is $\frac {A_1+\cdots +A_n}n$ (assuming there are $n$ objects).   But the probability that, say, there is exactly one object of type $A$ is $\sum_i \left(A_i\prod_{j\neq i}(1-A_j)\right)$ and it just gets worse if you want multiple objects.

Comment: But how about the uncertainty on the expected portion of type A objects?

Comment: I don't understand.  You should be able to compute the variance of the number of $A's$.  Just use $Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.  It's messy but perfectly doable,  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: No, as stated in my question above I am asking for a Bayesian way of propagating the uncertainty on the fraction estimator.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. There's nothing stopping you from working out the explicit probabilities, it's just a (very) tedious computation.  If you automate it, it shouldn't be that bad.  Usually, of course, mean and variance are all one really wants but sometimes exact distributions are called for.